# Abrir janela modal com função php passando por JS

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho necessidade de ao clica em um botão, abra um modal com uma form para inserção de dados em mysql.
Estou adaptando um código que eu usava anteriormente para exibir iframe, mas quando o modal abre ele mostra a pagina dentro do iframe com a função em php.
Preciso que somente dentro do modal abra a form para prencher.
Segue:

Administracao.php

```
 <li> <a role="button" data-toggle="modal" href="#insere" class="fa fa-info-circle"  style="font-size:18px"> Inserir</a></li>
  <div class="modal fade" id="insere" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close blank" title="Fechar" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title text-center">Inserir</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="900px" frameborder="none"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //função JS
  $('#insere').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#insere iframe').attr('src','?insere');
  });
     $('#insere').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
$('#insere iframe').removeAttr('src');
 });
 </script>
```

Comandos.php

```
if (isset($_GET['insere'])) {
<form id="executainserir" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<strong>Inserir documentos no banco de dados:</strong>
<table width="1075" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td width="180" scope="col">Título:
    <input name="titulo" type="text" autofocus required title="Título" size="30"></td>
  <td width="498" scope="col">Descrição:
    <input name="descricao" type="text" required title="Descrição" size="83"></td>
  <td width="375" scope="col">Link:
    <input name="link" type="url" value="http://" size="62"></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input name="arquivo" type="file" accept=".pdf" required title="Arquivo com extensão *.pdf" id="arquivo"><br> 
<input type="submit" name="executainserir" value="Gravar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você irá precisar de um **AJAX**.

Ao clicar no botão do modal, faça um GET via AJAX, retornando o conteúdo da página Comandos.php (que no caso seria o form html), com esse retorno, basta popular o elemento que irá exibir esse form (imagino que seria o `.modal-body`).

Answer (score 0):

Bem, antes de mais:

```
$('#insere iframe').attr('src','?insere');
```

deveria ser

```
$('#insere iframe').attr('src','comandos.php?insere');
```

No entanto, como disse o Denis Bernardo, o ideal é um pedido AJAX para comandos.php e idealmente com 'method' POST e abandonar o GET.

Presumo que o objectivo deste código seja fazer um upload com animação ou indicação de progresso, porém esta técnica (via iframe) é desencorajada ao máximo. Há alternativas mais leves, fáceis e mais seguras.
Ver: http://www.javascripture.com/FormData